# What level does the (Dragon)Mark of Healing cast Cure Wounds at?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, eberron

*Eberron: Rising from the Last War*:

Mark of Healing's feature Healing Touch says the following:

> You can cast the *cure wounds* spell with this trait

I'm assuming this can only be cast at 1st level, but I don't see that spelled out anywhere explicitly. Is that correct, and if so, can someone give me the citation? If not, how would you cast the spell at higher levels?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.